# Returning a message for the client in json format along with data - Java/Spring/REST

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, httpresponse

I would like to return a custom message along with data that my endpoint is supposed to return in `json` format. E.g:

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "name": "John",
 "surname": "Jackson",
 "city": "Los Angeles"
 "message": "There was only 1 person in chosen category"
}
```

So my POJO class of `person` has fields: `id`, `name`, `surname`, `city`. However I would like to return message too, so the client application can display the message on the front-end. I was looking for a solution. By default `Controller` endpoint can return the object as `json` no problem. But that just gives me data, `200` status and that's it. I found about returning `ResponseEntity`, but this doesn't solve the problem either since in response body it takes a POJO so I still can't send a custom message along with data. I need to send custom message, data and a proper status code.

Comment: Create a new class that wraps instances of your class and has `message` property and return instances of it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic class that you will return from your controllers which will enrich your models with `message` property :

```
public class ServerResponse {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private final Object wrapped;
    private final String message;

    public ServerResponse(Object wrapped, String message) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.message = message;
    }
    //getters
}
```

and then you can pass any object to this class in the constructor and let Jackson handle the serialization for you. This way you do not have to create a new class per your model :

```
User user = new User("1", "John", "Jackson", "Los Angeles");
ServerResponse serverResponse = new ServerResponse(user, "There was only 1 person in chosen category");
```

and when you return `ServerResponse` from the controller it will be serialized to :

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "name":"John",
   "surname":"Jackson",
   "city":"Los Angeles",
   "message":"message"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create new helper class(CustomUser) that have id, name, surname, city, message fields(getters and setters). And on sending you the user(new User with properties) on your controller, create new Instance of CustomUser class, set properties, and send customUser,
Like this:

```
CustomUser customUser = new CustomUser();
customUser.setId(user.getId);
customUser.setName(user.getName);
customUser.setSurname(user.getSurname);
customUser.setCity(user.getCity);
customUser.setMessage("Custom message");
```

Comment: I understand the idea however in case that I have multiple models/DTOs that I return I would have to create a helper class for every single one of them. I'm wondering about a solution though and I would like to know if what I think is correct. If I create an abstract class with one field: message and then my model/DTO classes will derive from it. I will have message field by default in each class. If I set that message field as Transient (using JPA notation), it won't be saving it to database, but I will be able to use it so send messages. Am I right here?

Comment: Yes that approach is correct. Also you can have a common method to prepare response as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use @MappedSuperclass and @Transient to solve your requirement.

Therefore you would have a base class like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public class BaseEntity {

    @Transient
    private String message; 

}
```

And your customer class would look like this:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String city;
}
```

This way you can add this field to all of your entities.